# Is it OK to install 32 bit linux on virtual pc on 64bit windows system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am trying to download ubuntu 32 bit to run in virtualbox. is it ok to run 32 bit os on virtual box in my windows 64bit pc? or do i need to download only 64 bit os to run in virtual box of my 64bit pc?

Comment: There's no harm and you probably prefer Lubuntu or Xubuntu in a virtual machine.

Comment: An advise : once you have it running, install gnome and use that. Default Unity environment is slow in VM

Comment: @AngelSalinasHuerta Thanks for commenting, i will download Lubuntu as its light weight than ubuntu.

Comment: @Serg Thank you. I am trying lubuntu as said by above user. It has  LXDE desktop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Yes**, on a computer that support 64bit, you can run 64bit or 32bit OS VMS with out any problem but reverse is not true.

That's mean, you cannot use 64bit OS on a computer that support only 32bit.

And, if you are really looking for a light weight Ubuntu flavor distro, I would recommend [Elementry OS](https://elementary.io/)

Of course, there are lot of light weight distro but with Elementry OS, I had very good experience : fast and stable.

Comment: Thanks!. I already have ubuntu image, so could you tell me how to make it run faster on Virtual machine?

Comment: Actually, there is not magical solution or answer. It's all depend, how much ressource that you provide to VM and how you use the VM.

You can add more RAM, CPU and disable unwanted software.. but at the end, you have to adjust depend on your usage and needs.

This link might help you : http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-ubuntu-overall-system-performance

Comment: Yam Gotham this links says `You can't run a 64-bit VM session on a 32-bit processor`. [Can I run a 64-bit VMware image on a 32-bit machine?] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56124/can-i-run-a-64-bit-vmware-image-on-a-32-bit-machine)

Comment: @AngRed yes, but the OP wants to run a 32bit VM on a 64bit machine. That's quite different.

Comment: @AngRed I completely  agree with what the link said. What I want / mean to say is that : if your computer does not support 64 bit , you cannot install 64bit host OS or even 64bit VM OS So, you can only install 32bit OS. But you if your machine support 64bit, you can install 32bit or 64bit OS with no problem. Sorry for confusion but I thought it was clear what I said before.

Answer (score -2):

Virtual Machine is just an ENV for the VM's.
You can install 32 bit or i686 OS on any 64 bit Host OS as a VM

Virtual Machine is just an ENV for the VM's.

Install the VM tray & Guest Addition tools for better performance.

Comment: Thanks for answering. could you tell me how to make ubuntu run faster on virtual machine, like how to install gnome and uninstall unity